# Automatically log out from application when all tabs are closed in browser

Tags: oracle-apex

I was trying to do automatically logout when all tabs of application are closed.Please let me know if anyone have idea to solve my problem.

Actually I was trying to check duplicate login till session expired.
I successfully done coding to check duplicate login but it failed when I closed tab and re-login with same credential.It shows me message of duplicate login which I have implemented for other machin.

Hence I was looking for solution that once all tabs of application has closed then it should clear session of that user without waiting session idle time to expire.So that immediate login after all tabs get closed would be allowed to same user.

Comment: Sounds like you might be trying to solve the wrong problem here … Why is a “duplicate login” (by which you mean what exactly – just the user having your app open in multiple browser tabs?) a problem for your app?

Comment: Duplicate login means multiple login with same credentials,Basically I want to avoid feature of multi-login by same user ,I was expecting to show message to one who try login which is already login somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

First of all APEX is a stateless system.
Once a page is rendered, it no longer has connection to the database. The DB does not know the difference between you login and then closing the tab or you log in and do noting on that page.

The only two javascript events that detects that you want to close the tab are `onunload` & `onbeforeunload`. The problem is that those events are also fired when you leave a site over a link or over your browsers back button. So they are not very helpful in letting the DB know you have closed the tab.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,there might be another solution to overcome this problem.I am constantly looking other sites too.I am still curious to know such implementation.